# Self Modifying Python? How can I redirect all print statements within a function without touching sys.stdout?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a situation where I am attempting to port some big, complex python routines to a threaded environment.

I want to be able to, on a per-call basis, redirect the output from the function's `print` statement somewhere else (a `logging.Logger` to be specific).

I really don't want to modify the source for the code I am compiling, because I need to maintain backwards compatibility with other software that calls these modules (which is single threaded, and captures output by simply grabbing everything written to `sys.stdout`).

I know the best option is to do some rewriting, but I really don't have a choice here.

**Edit** -

Alternatively, is there any way I can override the local definition of print to point to a different function?

I could then define the local print = system print unless overwritten by a kwarg, and would only involve modify a few lines at the beginning of each routine.

Comment: why can't you touch sys.stdout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python2.6 (and 2.7), you can use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Then you can change the code to use the `print()` function as you would for Python3

This allows you to create a module global or local function called print which will be used in preference to the builtin function

eg.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def f(x, print=print):
    print(x*x)

f(5)
L=[]
f(6, print=L.append)
print(L)
```

Comment: I guess this is as good as it gets. Is there any way to remove the need for the parentheses?

Comment: Hah, it certainly freaks out netbean's syntax checker.

Comment: @Fake, afraid you'll have to use the parens if you do it this way :)

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the source code doesn't need to imply breaking backward compatibility.

What you need to do is first replace every print statement with a call to a function that does the same thing:

```
import sys
def _print(*args, **kw):
    sep = kw.get('sep', ' ')
    end = kw.get('end', '\n')
    file = kw.get('file', sys.stdout)
    file.write(sep.join(args))
    file.write(end)

def foo():
   # print "whatever","you","want"
   _print("whatever","you","want")
```

Then the second step is to stop using the _print function directly and make it a keyword argument:

```
def foo(_print=_print):
    ...
```

and make sure to change all internal function calls to pass the _print function around.

Now all the existing code will continue to work and will use print, but you can pass in whatever _print function you want.

Note that the signature of _print is exactly that of the print function in more recent versions of Python, so as soon as you  upgrade you can just change it to use `print()`. Also you may get away with using 2to3 to migrate the print statements in the existing code which should reduce the editing required.

Comment: I know, I was just hoping to avoid significant refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

Someone in the sixties had an idea about how to solve this but it requires a bit of alien technology. Unfortunately python has no "current environment" concept and this means you cannot provide context unless specifying it in calls as a parameter.

For handling just this specific problem what about replacing stdout with a file-like object that behaves depending on a thread-specific context ? This way the source code remains the same but for example you can get a separate log for each thread. It's even easy to do this on a specific per-call way... for example:

```
class MyFakeStdout:
    def write(self, s):
        try:
            separate_logs[current_thread()].write(s)
        except KeyError:
            old_stdout.write(s)
```

and then having a function to set a logger locally to a call (`with`)

PS: I saw the "without touching stdout" in the title but I thought this was because you wanted only some thread to be affected. Touching it while still allowing other threads to work unaffected seems to me compatible with the question.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Hmmmm.