# Appending tabs to all print statements in Python

Tags: python, formatting

I'm writing a Python console application, and I would like its output to be tabbed one tab over to set it apart from the command line.

Is there a single-command way to have tabs in front of all print statements without having to type each one explicitly?

Thank you!

Comment: You could create a function `my_print` that behaves as you want, then change all your `print` calls to the new function.

Comment: Or use `logging` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any setting in Python to be able to do that, the easiest way would be to create a new function like so.

```
def printTab(*args):
    args = ("\t",)+args
    print(*args)
```

> Comment on other answers:
>
> If you let your new function take a single argument, rather than multiple arguments (using `*args`, you lose a lot of the functionality in the Python 3 `print` function.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is just create an alternate print command for this specific use. It might look something like this:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

def print_tabbed(str_to_print):
    print('\t{}'.format(str_to_print))
```

Answer (score 0):

While there may be a way to do what you ask [(see this link if that's really what you want)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573727/self-modifying-python-how-can-i-redirect-all-print-statements-within-a-function), I think it's a bad idea and you could improve a bit on this solution.

If you define a function like this :

```
def printWithTab("text"):
    print("\t{}").format(text)
```

You could use this function instead.

```
>>>print(test)
test

>>> printWithTab("test")
    test
```

(assuming python 3+)